# Behavior of so_error for socket and epoll

Tags: sockets, unix, epoll

I have read this sentence from the *Unix Network Programming* book

> If so_error is nonzero when the process calls read and there is no
>   data to return, read returns–1 with errno set to the value of so_error
>   (p. 516 of TCPv2). The value of so_error is then reset to 0. If there
>   is data queued for the socket, that data is returned by read instead
>   of the error condition. If so_error is nonzero when the process calls
>   write, –1 is returned with errno set to the value of so_error (p. 495
>   of TCPv2) and so_error is reset to 0.

It seems to indicate, if I understand it correctly, that the SO_ERROR option is not reset to 0 if there is data to read from the socket: *If there is data queued for the socket, that data is returned by read instead of the error condition*

I am wondering what would be the behavior when using epoll to monitor this socket.

The first event would contains the `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLERR` flags which make sense. A call to `read()` on this socket would return the data instead of the error, assuming there is queued data, as mentioned in the sentence.

Now, imagine that I rearm the socket to the epoll instance, would it report `EPOLLERR` for this socket on the next call to `epoll_wait`, given the fact that no more data is queued ? That is what I am assuming since nothing in the quoted sentence indicates that SO_ERROR has been reset after the previous `read()` call, but I could be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You are correct. This seems really only to apply usefully to read timeouts, as all other errors on a socket are fatal to both the connection and any pending-read data. So for example if a read timeout triggered and you took a while to notice it and meanwhile data arrived, you would get the data, not the timeout. But then why the timeout error should still hang around is a mystery. Note that this is about `so_error`, a field in the kernel, not the `getsockopt()` option `SO_ERROR`, although they are of course related.

Comment: @user207421 So in non-blocking mode, I guess this wouldn't happen. You say: "So for example if a read timeout triggered and you took a while to notice it", but I am not sure to fully understand what you mean, because to my understanding the timeout would produce a partial return of the data available or errno set to [EAGAIN] or [EWOULDBLOCK] if no data is received.
I failed to mention that I am working with sockets in non-blocking mode in my current usecase.

Comment: Correct. No read timeouts in non-blocking mode. So the bit you didn't understand isn't relevant; but if there was a read timeout there is *no* 'partial return of the data', because there is no data at all, which is why the timeout occurred.

Comment: @user207421 I guess it explain why libevent is treating EPOLLHUP and EPOLLERR this way here: https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/33053cdd8a9e1a7330b47759dee9cb209bed8f1b/epoll.c#L489

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for your answers.